# solution to this design?

Tags: html, css

i was looking forward to some designs as done [here](http://zealot-ece.webs.com/).

how is it possible for the background to remain static and the content to move over it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CSS and Backgrounds](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/stylesheets/cssbackgrounds.html)

```
<body bgproperties="fixed" background="image">
```

or

```
body {background-image: url(../images/tile.gif); background-attachment: fixed; }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
background-attachment: fixed
```

You can find this sort of stuff out easily by using a tool that lets you examine the CSS applied via the browser, such as Firebug for Firefox or Web Inspector for WebKit.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at source :

```
html {
    background: transparent url(http://images.freewebs.com/Members/Generationz/CSSStyles/Elements/Water/bg-body.jpg) repeat fixed 0% 0%;
}
```

It's the "fixed" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
background: transparent url('http://file.jpg') repeat fixed top left;
```

`fixed` is the key.

Answer (score 0):

You should have:

```
background: transparent url('image path here') repeat top left;
background-attachment: fixed
```